# Terminal shows "Couldn't open audio: Couldn't open audio device or ESD connection" after launching a game and there is no sound in the game

Tags: games, pulseaudio, alsa

So I tried installing a Heroes of Might and Magic 3 linux loki game version into Ubuntu 13.10  and everything is fine but I don't have sound. When I try to launch a game through a terminal it throws an error:

```
Couldn't open audio: Couldn't open audio device or ESD connection
```

and when the game launches, there is no sound. What could be the problem?

Comment: You should post it in Q&A form, where you have a question and then an answer with the solution. Self-answering is encouraged.

Comment: Please create an answer to your own question bellow instead of including it on the question it self. As it is the format does not fit a Q&A site and is more fit for a forum. Just copy the text from your question and post it as an answer please.

Comment: This needs to be converted to a Q&A format, after editing and creating an answer this can re-opened :)

Comment: Sorry, yeah, i already wanted to post an answer as suggested by 3ventic. I'm a newbie so i don't really know how to post an answer if thread is closed - i mean, i edited my question to 'be' question - but i can't write an answer. How do i do that?

Comment: @astar: Now, since you have edited the question (which is a question) - community members would vote to reopen it. Once the question gets reopened, you should be able to post your answer (however, since you are a new user, you might have to wait for a couple of hours before you can answer your own question). In short, just have some patience :-)

Comment: Hi @astar, I found your question very useful. Could you post the answer?

Answer (score 0):

You may just need to install `osspd`

```
apt install osspd
```

Tested successfully in Ubuntu 18.10 with an old Linux game

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]! Could you [edit] your answer to explain _how_ this helps?